# Running gulp.series programmatically from Node app does not run all tasks

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

**The objective:** Run gulp tasks programmatically from within a node application to be used at run time of application.

**The problem**: Only the first two tasks in `gulp.series` are being run (`clean` and `handlebars`), `inline` task is being completely skipped.

**The Question:** Can anyone tell me why only the first two tasks seem to run?

The following code is in a file called `app.js`. I run the file by typing `node app.js` in the terminal.

**Here is my code:** Please scroll to see full code.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const rename = require('gulp-rename');
const inlineCSS = require('gulp-inline-css');
const clean = require('gulp-clean');
const panini = require('panini');

//Compile Handlebars templates
gulp.task('handlebars', async function () {
    return gulp
        .src('views/pages/*.hbs')
        .pipe(
            panini({
                root: 'views/pages',
                layouts: 'views/layouts',
                partials: 'views/partials',
            })
        )
        .pipe(
            rename(function (path) {
                path.basename += '-send';
                path.extname = '.html';
            })
        )
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/inline-html'));
});

//Inline CSS from app.css into compiled HTML files
gulp.task('inline', async function () {
    return gulp
        .src('dist/inline-html/*.html')
        .pipe(inlineCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/send-html'));
});

//Clean dist folder
gulp.task('clean', async function () {
    return gulp.src('dist/**/*', { read: false }).pipe(clean());
});

async function gulpTaskRunner() {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        gulp.series('clean', 'handlebars', 'inline', (done) => {
            console.log('Gulp task completed');
            resolve();
            done();
        })();
    });
}

async function app() {
    console.log('start');
    await gulpTaskRunner();
    console.log('end');
}

app();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the problem could be in your `inline` task:

```
//Inline CSS from app.css into compiled HTML files
gulp.task('inline', async function () {
    return gulp
        .src('dist/inline-html/*.html')
        .pipe(inlineCSS())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/send-html'));
});
```

It returns immediately with a fulfilled promise of a gulp stream. So the task is considered as complete and the app finishes without waiting your streams. Just remove `async` from it.

Comment: Thank you! That worked. I don't fully understand why it worked, but it worked.

Comment: Why did it work for other tasks if they are async as well though?

Comment: @Konrad seems the transform plugins are using sync `transform(file, enc, cb)` so they are able to process data

Comment: @Pajama_Jeans and yes, as mentioned by Konrad you could remove `async` from other tasks too

Comment: @Konrad but you're right, `async` should be removed from other tasks too. I just didn't bother to check them since they were working. node streams could be intricate